# Why can we take the colimit over the category of elements?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, fundamental-group, etale-covers

I'm trying to understand J. P. Murre's [Tata notes on Grothendieck's theory of the fundamental group](https://mathweb.tifr.res.in/sites/default/files/publications/ln/tifr40.pdf). For a Galois category $\mathcal C$ (which I'm taking to be locally small) with fundamental functor $F : \mathcal C \to \mathsf{FinSet}$, Murre shows that $F$ is pro-representable by showing that $F(X)$ is naturally isomorphic to $\operatorname*{colim}_{(S, \tau) \in \mathcal I^\mathrm{op}}\operatorname{Hom}_\mathcal C(S, X)$, where $\mathcal I$ is the full subcategory of the category of elements $\mathcal E$ consisting of minimal pairs. A pair $(S, \tau)$ is *minimal* if whenever
$$
j : (X, \xi) \to (S, \tau)
$$
is a morphism in $\mathcal E$ with $j : X \hookrightarrow S$ monic in $\mathcal C$, in fact $j$ is an isomorphism. My concern is that, although Murre calls $\mathcal E$ a set, it seems like $\mathcal I$ might not be a small category if $\mathcal C$ itself is not small, so I don't see how we know that $\operatorname*{colim}_{(S, \tau) \in \mathcal I^\mathrm{op}}\operatorname{Hom}_\mathcal C(S, X)$ exists.

I was told that the category of étale coverings over a fixed locally Noetherian connected prescheme is (essentially?) small, and if that's true, then I could believe that the categories of finite separable extensions of a fixed field and covering spaces over a fixed connected space (the categories I want to show are Galois for a presentation I need to give) are also (essentially) small, so should I just assume that a Galois category is (essentially) small? Alternatively, is there an argument that shows $\mathcal I^\mathrm{op}$ is cofinally small, perhaps using the fact that $\mathcal E^\mathrm{op}$ is filtered?

Comment: These notes https://mathweb.tifr.res.in/sites/default/files/publications/ln/tifr40.pdf ?

Comment: I'm a little confused: if you say Murre proves that the colimit you are asking about is F(X), that also shows it exists. Or does Murre somehow only show the colimit is F(X) under the assumption that the colimit exists? That's possible but sounds unlikely.

Comment: If $\mathcal{I}$ is a full subcategory of $\mathcal{E}$, and the latter is known to be a set (i.e. small, in modern terminology), then you are done. So the trick is to see that $\mathcal{E}$ is (essentially) small.

Comment: Murre proves that the resulting cocone over the indicated diagram of sets is a colimit cocone.  In particular, his argument proves that the colimit exists.

Comment: It depends what *exactly* you mean by pro-representable. As Omar points out  presumably the existence of the colimit *follows* from.the arguments. But if the indexing set is large (and that can happen if $\mathcal C$ is not assumed small from the start) then the representing "pro-object" is a large pro-object and as such not usually called a pro-object

Comment: @DavidRoberts those are the ones! Though the copy I'm looking at is typewritten T_T

Comment: @OmarAntolín-Camarena If I'm understanding the proof correctly, Murre uses the universal property of the colimit to produce a function $\operatorname*{colim}_{(S, \tau) \in \mathcal I^\mathrm{op}} \to F(X)$, then argues that this is both a surjection and an injection.

Comment: And it seems to me like the proof of injectivity relies on the description of the colimit as a quotient of the disjoint union.

Comment: The category of finite étale covers of a locally Noetherian scheme is essentially small; in fact, even the category of finitely presented $X$-schemes is essentially small for any scheme $X$. This is an exercise in unwinding what 'finitely presented' means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, a cosequence of the arguments in Murre's proof is that the inclusion $J^{\text{op}}\colon\mathcal I^{\text{op}}\hookrightarrow \mathcal E ^{\text{op}}$ is a [final functor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/final+functor): It's easy to see that if $H\colon \mathcal A\hookrightarrow \mathcal B$ is fully faithful and $\mathcal B$ is filtered, then $H$ is final if and only if for any $b\in\mathcal B$ there exists $a\in\mathcal A$ and a map $b\to Ha$ in $\mathcal B$. In your case this condition is satisfied by point (*) of the proof.

Now use the property of final functors applied to $J^{\text{op}}$: this says (in particular) that if the colimit of $G\colon \mathcal E^{\text{op}}\to \mathcal K$ exists, then also the colimit of $GJ^{\text{op}}\colon \mathcal I^{\text{op}}\to\mathcal K$ exists, and in that case they coincide. In your situation we already know that the colimit indexed on $\mathcal E^{\text{op}}$ exists and is equal to $F$ (it is always true, independently of the size of $\mathcal C$, that any functor $F\colon \mathcal C\to \text{Set}$ is the colimit of the diagram indexed on the category of elements), thus you can conclude.

Comment: The part about this always being true was the part that I was missing, thanks! Do you have a nice reference for this, or would you mind saying a bit more about how to show this?

Comment: See the proof of Theorem 2.15.6 from the Handbook of categorical algebra, Volume 1, by Borceux. The result is stated for $\mathcal C$ small, but the proof also works for large ones (since he proves directly that $F$ satisfies the universal property, rather then assuming that the colimit exists and proving that the comparison map is an iso).